# an adjective meaning a question which can be answered several ways

Tags: adjectives

It's sort of similar to the term *open-ended*. It's also sort of similar to the word *ambiguous*.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a question?

Comment: An average ELU  question :)

Comment: An *open* question is one that does not have any particular answer. It is not even limited to a set number of choices, so it might be more general that what you are requesting. An *open* question is an invitation for the interlocutor to share their ideas about the subject, whatever they might be.

Comment: How about a _multifaceted_ question?  (I also take it you're not speaking about a _multiple-choice_ question?)

Answer (score 1):

A *subjective* question can be answered in many ways.

Comment: @tchrist - I'm trying to get the hand of your editing style.  Why does Flan get away with all that bold but William doesn't?

Comment: @aparente001 I get tired of typing.

Comment: @aparente001 Ah, I see.  I was using boldface for words I was defining, like in a dictionary or encyclopedia.  I would use italics inline, such as in an example sentence.  But tchrist seems to prefer using italics in both cases, so I'll follow his preference from now on!

Comment: @Flan - I think your bold was fine for definitions. You could have changed the last one to italics and left the other three in bold, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Some subtle differences here, depending on the tone you're going for. From Dictionary.Reference.Com:

> -
> *[Controvertible](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/controvertible):* Arguable; debatable.
>
> -
> *[Equivocal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equivocal/):* Allowing the possibility of several different meanings, [...] especially with intent to deceive or misguide; susceptible of double interpretation.
>
> -
> *[Obscure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obscure):* Not clear or plain; ambiguous, vague, or uncertain.

If you can give more context, that might be helpful.

Comment: But *ambiguous* is ambiguous!  It might mean that the question isn't worded clearly.

Comment: Also "sibylline" (i.e. mysterious, cryptic, difficult to understand).

Answer (score 0):

A *multi-solution* question.  (I made that up.)

I also support "subjective".